# Should Android Studio be run with sudo on Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, sudo

I am facing issues when I need to, for example, download new Build-tools using the Standalone SDK Manager. It says it does not have permissions etc - so I run ./studio.sh with sudo, which fixes the problem.

I have not faced more problems yet, but what is the right way of running Android Studio on Linux - with, or without sudo rights? I do not want grant it rights if it can do without it.

Just to mention, **Android Studio is placed at /opt/android-studio/...**
And the **SDK at ~/Android/Sdk/...** (to my understanding this should not need root privileges?)

**UPDATE**
I keep getting access errors if running without sudo and simply trying to build the project.

> Could not read path
>   '/home/fakepath/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/0.4.4/jni'

Comment: in theory, if you wanted to run it as your own user, you could do that by changing ownership of the entire /opt/android-studio directory (recursively).

Comment: sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /home/fakepath/app

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the best solution so far the worked for me is a constructive answer:

- **sudo for Android Studio?**

  > It's usually good to minimize the programs you need to run as root. - @Kyle

  *Run Android Studio without sudo*
- **sudo for SDK Manager only**

  > You can run just the SDK manager by running the shell script "android" in the android-sdk/tools folder
  >   **sudo sh /opt/android-sdk/tools/android** - @Kyle

  *Launch SDK Manager separately when an update is needed*
- **Granting file access permissions**

  > if you wanted to run it as your own user, you could do that by changing ownership of the entire /opt/android-studio directory (recursively) - @matias elgart
  >
  > **sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /home/fakepath/app** - @num8er

  So in my case, I have changed the **ownership of Android SDK folder** for Android Studio to pick up the files without any problems. This has solved my issues:

  ```
  sudo chown -R myusername:myusername ~/fakepath/Android/Sdk/
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually good to minimize the programs you need to run as root. You can run just the SDK manager by running the shell script "android" in the android-sdk/tools folder

```
$ sh /opt/android-sdk/tools/android
```

Comment: My android sdk lies in ~/Android/Sdk/... 
So I am confused why in the first place I received the Permissions error in the Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install Android Studio and correctly map it tools:

1. Install requirements:

   sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
2. [Download](https://developer.android.com/studio) and move Android Studio to /opt/android-studio

   tar -xzvf android-studio-*.tar.gz
   sudo mv android-studio /opt
3. Run the install script at /opt/android-studio/bin

   cd /opt/android-studio/bin
   ./studio.sh
4. Edit your .bashrc adding path to android_home

   export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
   source ~/.bashrc
5. Now you can access tools without sudo

   adb devices

Note: After running the install script studio.sh it will install and SDK to /root and also to /home, if you points to /root you will need to use sudo, but instead points to /home (~/Android)